# In MySQL, how is it possible that a DATETIME column is AHEAD of the `updated_at` column with a `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` configuration?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, timestamp, amazon-rds

Suppose I have a `users` table with a `name_updated_at` column (`DATETIME DEFAULT NULL`) and an `updated_at` column (`DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)

Also suppose I have an Expressjs API with an endpoint to update a users name.

Upon updating a users name, we manually set the `name_updated_at` column with something like the following query:

```
UPDATE users SET name_updated_at = "2023-10-02 15:59:38" WHERE id = 1234;
```

This would trigger the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for the `updated_at` column.

Somehow, the `updated_at` column is being set to 1 second BEFORE the `name_updated_at` column

[image: db_issue]

How is this possible? Is this discrepancy created by the fact that the Expressjs API is somehow milliseconds/seconds AHEAD of the MySQL server?

As for a little more context, both the Expressjs API and the MySQL database are running on AWS. EC2 and RDS, respectively. There doesn't seem to be any indication of high traffic/usage on these services.

Comment: The clocks aren't synchronized?

Comment: It might be rounding milliseconds differently.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this discrepancy created by the fact that the Expressjs API is somehow milliseconds/seconds AHEAD of the MySQL server?

The clocks may not be exactly syncronized on the two different servers However, you are also generating the value at different times of the process.

- Once in ExpressApi
- Once during the execution of the MySQL update.

Both values have merit, but represent two different stages of your MySQL transaction. When you sent your request from the api, and the other timestamp comes from when the MySQL server processes the update statement. Which may have a little lag from sending and receiving messages for each server.